# How to make coffee beans move on impact?

Tags: animation, collision

I've created a scene where coffee beans are on the ground, and a coffee package falls onto them. However, the issue I'm facing is that when the package falls, it only drops, bounces slightly, and that's it. Coffee beans don't move at all and they don't react to the impact.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could make a hundred of coffee beans that have rigid body fall on the ground, bake to keyframes once they don't move anymore, then give them back rigid body, make the coffee pack fall with a high mass value so that it pushes the beans (maybe also create a *Force Field > Force* to increase the explosive effect, if the pack has a high mass it will be less affected). You can can also add coffee beans with a particle system (but of course they won't move):

[image]